# Cannot create a new column in MySQL using workbench, why?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, phpmyadmin

I am currently running linux mint. The MySQL tutorial that I am using calls for workbench GUI along with XAMPP.

As usual, support for linux is crap. I had to make do with the workbench ubuntu file. Although I did force an install, workbench said that there could be errors since Mint is unsupported.

And now I am getting errors.

I ran the following code in workbench:

```
CREATE DATABASE companyHR;
USE companyHR;

CREATE TABLE co_employees (
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
em_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
contact_number VARCHAR(255),
age INT NOT NULL,
date_created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);

RENAME TABLE co_employees TO employees;
COMMIT;

ALTER TABLE employees
DROP COLUMN age,
ADD COLUMN salary FLOAT;

COMMIT;
```

however, I dont see the salary column in the MySQL workbench -> schema inspector -> columns tab.

Why is this happening?

i shutdown the workbench GUI, stopped XAMPP and started all over. Just to make note of all errors workbench throws up.

I startup up workbench GUI and connect. The SQL practice file is loaded. On the left pane, I rightclick the companyHR database and select schema inspector. Thats when the first error message pops up:

> An error occurred retrieving information about the schema. Query: show
> procedure status where Db = 'companyHR' Error: Column count of
> mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created iwth MariaDB
> 100108, now running 100425. Please mysql_upgrade to fix this error.

I then click OK. The SAME error message then appears for the second time. I again click OK. This time around, another error message shows up:

> An error occurred retrieving information about the schema.
> Query: show events from `companyHR`
> Error: Cannot proceed, because event scheduler is disabled.

I then click OK yet again. This time, the companyHR schema details show up with the following tabs in order from left to right: info, tables, columns, indexes, triggers, views, stored procedures, functions, grants, events

I click on the columns tab because I expect a 'salary' column owing to this command in the code above: 'ADD COLUMN salary FLOAT;'

But there is no such column. From top to bottom in the columns tab, I can see id, em_name, gender, contact_number and date_created only.

Why is 'salary' column missing?

furthermore, when I leftclick on the companyHR database on the left pane under the Schemas tab, I see the following dropdown list:

- Tables could not be fetched
- Views could not be fetched
- Stored Procedures could not be fetched
- Functions could not be fetched

The same dropdown list appears under 'phpmyadmin' and 'test' in the left pane.

pls help.

Comment: remember, since I am running linux mint, I had to install the MySQL workbench ubuntu file since this is the closest that can work. I am sure this is causing these problems. but what can I do?

Comment: Pull up a "terminal" and use the commandline "mysql".  Be sure to properly include user, password and host (probably "localhost").  In that, you can run those same commands and immediately get any errors.  (UIs tend to filter the errors and obfuscate them.)  If it ever says "Warnings", then promptly do `SHOW WARNINGS;`, some of them could be very important.

Comment: Did you consider running "mysql_upgrade to fix this error", as suggested by the error message?

Comment: yes, tried that, I type mysql_upgrade in the command line and get this error message.

Comment: The mysql_upgrade client is now deprecated. The actions executed by the upgrade client are now done by the server.
To upgrade, please start the new MySQL binary with the older data directory. Repairing user tables is done automatically. Restart is not required after upgrade.
The upgrade process automatically starts on running a new MySQL binary with an older data directory. To avoid accidental upgrades, please use the --upgrade=NONE option with the MySQL binary. The option --upgrade=FORCE is also provided to run the server upgrade sequence on demand.

Comment: It may be possible that the server upgrade fails due to a number of reasons. 
In that case, the upgrade sequence will run again during the next MySQL server start. If the server upgrade fails repeatedly, the server can be started 
with the --upgrade=MINIMAL option to start the server without executing the upgrade sequence, thus allowing users to manually rectify the problem.

Comment: @Rick James command line? Find it hard, but will give it a go. using this link: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql/connect-to-mysql-server/ . It says to go to the bin in the mysql installation folder. I have xampp. I open CL in /opt/lampp/bin. Type 'mysql'. But this error shows: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2). Any ideas?

Comment: have no clue what happened, but the salary column now appears just like that in both workbench and phpmyadmin
no idea whats going on. 

However, I am still getting the error message that I described previously. In the workbench left pane under the schemas tab, this is what I see:
    Tables could not be fetched
    Views could not be fetched
    Stored Procedures could not be fetched
    Functions could not be fetched

Comment: `mysql` needs arguments such as user and password.  Check the syntax for more details.

Comment: @Rick James thanks for the suggestion. The following command worked: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root